# 2 column layout that extends the length of the page as content is added to sidebar div

Tags: html, css

I'm working on building a page with a 2 column layout, header, and footer. I'm using div's, html, and css.

**The Problem I'm Experiencing** is the left column that is created by div#sideBar extends over the footer when content is added.

**The Solution I'm Looking For** is I'd like the left column to 'push' the footer down and extend the length of the div#contentWrapper when more content is added to the div#sideBar.

I've looked through several tutorials, but I can't seem to figure it out. Can someone please direct me to a tutorial that will solve this problem or help me modify the code below so the page it creates will extend (push down footer) as content is added to the div#sideBar?

**The ScreenShot below shows the result of the code below.**

[image]

```
<style type="text/css">
#wrapper {
    width: 900px;
    margin: auto;
}
#header {
    background-color: #0F0;
}
#contentWrapper {
    background-color: #FF0;
}
#footer {
    background-color: #00F;
}
#sideBar {
    float: left;
    width: 200px;
    height: 100%;
    color: #F00;
}
#content {
    width: 700px;
    margin-left: 200px;
    background-color: #FFF;
}
p {
    margin: 0px;
}
</style>
</head>

<body>
<div id="wrapper">
  <div id="header">
    Home | Page One | Page Two  </div>
  <div id="contentWrapper">
    <div id="sideBar">
      <p>
        <ul>
  <li>Home</li>
  <li>Page One</li>
  <li> Page Two</li>
</ul>
      </p>
      <p>hgfds</p>
      <p>kgjkfhghf</p>
      <p>jkfhgjdffgfhj</p>
      <p>ljkfhgjdf</p>
      <p>;klgjhg</p>
      <p>lkgjhfg</p>
      <p>lgkjhfg</p>
      <p>&nbsp;</p>
    </div>
    <div id="content">
      <p>Content for  id "content" Goes Here</p>
      <p>&nbsp;</p>
      <p>&nbsp;</p>
      <p>&nbsp;</p>
    </div>
  </div>
  <div id="footer">
    <p>CopyRight 2014</p>
<p>Home | Page One | Page Two</p>
  </div>
</div>
</body>
</html>
```

Answer (score 0):

```
#footer {
    background-color: #00F;
    clear:both;
}
```

You need to clear the float used in the sideBar, which you can do in the footer.

```
#sideBar {
    float: left;
    width: 200px;
    height: 100%;
    color: #F00;
}
```

Unless you also need to expand the background of in which case you need to add a tag inside the wrapper that clears the floats

```
    </div> <!-- content div -->
    <div style="clear:left"></div>
  </div> <!-- wrapper div -->
  <div id="footer">
```

Answer (score 0):

Easiest way would be to use `display:table;` on a container that the sidebar and main content area both share and set the two child divs to `display:table-cell;`

HTML:

```
<div class="container">
    <div class="sidebar">
        <ul>
            <li>item 1</li>
            <li>item 1</li>
            <li>item 1</li>
            <li>item 1</li>
            <li>item 1</li>
            <li>item 1</li>
            <li>item 1</li>
            <li>item 1</li>
            <li>item 1</li>
            <li>item 1</li>
            <li>item 1</li>
            <li>item 1</li>
            <li>item 1</li>

        </ul>
    </div>
    <div class="main">
        main content main content main content main content main content main content main content main content main content main content main content main content main content main content main
    </div>    
</div>
```

CSS:

```
.container {
    width:100%;
    display:table;
}
.sidebar, .main {
    width:50%;
    display:table-cell;
}
.main {
    background:#eee;
}
.sidebar {
    background:#666;
}
```

http://jsfiddle.net/3gbfnpua/3/

Answer (score -1):

You can solve this by adding this to your css:

```
.clearfix:after {
    content: ".";
    display: block;
    clear: both;
    visibility: hidden;
    line-height: 0;
    height: 0;
}

.clearfix {
    display: inline-block;
}

html[xmlns] .clearfix {
    display: block;
}

* html .clearfix {
    height: 1%;
}
```

Then add `class="clearfix"` to any element you want to extend.

There's a lot of information about Clearfix on StackOverflow (and elsewhere on the internet). Try [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8554043/what-is-clearfix), for example.

```css
#wrapper {
  width: 900px;
  margin: auto;
}
#header {
  background-color: #0F0;
}
#contentWrapper {
  background-color: #FF0;
}
#footer {
  background-color: #00F;
}
#sideBar {
  float: left;
  width: 200px;
  height: 100%;
  color: #F00;
}
#content {
  width: 700px;
  margin-left: 200px;
  background-color: #FFF;
}
p {
  margin: 0px;
}
.clearfix:after {
  content: ".";
  display: block;
  clear: both;
  visibility: hidden;
  line-height: 0;
  height: 0;
}
.clearfix {
  display: inline-block;
}
html[xmlns] .clearfix {
  display: block;
}
* html .clearfix {
  height: 1%;
}
```

```html
<div id="wrapper">
  <div id="header">
    Home | Page One | Page Two</div>
  <div id="contentWrapper" class="clearfix">
    <div id="sideBar">
      <p>
        <ul>
          <li>Home</li>
          <li>Page One</li>
          <li>Page Two</li>
        </ul>
      </p>
      <p>hgfds</p>
      <p>kgjkfhghf</p>
      <p>jkfhgjdffgfhj</p>
      <p>ljkfhgjdf</p>
      <p>;klgjhg</p>
      <p>lkgjhfg</p>
      <p>lgkjhfg</p>
      <p>&nbsp;</p>
    </div>
    <div id="content">
      <p>Content for id "content" Goes Here</p>
      <p>&nbsp;</p>
      <p>&nbsp;</p>
      <p>&nbsp;</p>
    </div>
  </div>
  <div id="footer">
    <p>CopyRight 2014</p>
    <p>Home | Page One | Page Two</p>
  </div>
</div>
```